# Create ToolTip for Custom UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to understand how to utilize a `ToolTip` with a custom `UserControl`. Just creating the ToolTip on a form and assigning the specific control a ToolTip (via `SetToolTip`) obviously will not work.

What properties do I need to give the custom UserControl in order to assign ToolTip text to it? Do I need to add a ToolTip on the usercontrol form? How can I go about doing this?

Please provide a code sample or something for me to visualize.

Thank you!

Comment: what do you have so far.. and what do you mean won't work...?

Comment: The UserControl needs to take care of tooltips itself.

Comment: I created a ToolTip and placed it into my UserControl. Problem is finding the correct Get Set values in order to pass a value to the ToolTip

Comment: Are you looking for a tooltip for each item in the UserControl, or just one for the UserControl as a whole?

Comment: Just one item in the usercontrol, a textbox. The usercontrol only has two items, textbox and label. Label does not concern me. Only the textbox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a ToolTip on your UserControl (use the designer, just like you would put one on a form), and add a public property to your UserControl like:

```
    public string TextBoxHint
    {
        get 
        { 
            return toolTip1.GetToolTip(textBox1); 
        }
        set
        {
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, value);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I got pretty much that far but just didn't have the Get and Set completely correct. Brain drain.

Comment: @igbylargeman can we set the tooltip to **this** userControl as well? I couldn't make it work. What I did was `toolTip1.SetToolTip(this, value);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create **SetToolTip** method in user control and set tooltip for each user control's subcontrol:

   ```
    public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public void SetToolTip(ToolTip toolTip)
        {
            string text = toolTip.GetToolTip(this);

            toolTip.SetToolTip(subControl1, text);
            toolTip.SetToolTip(subControl2, text);
            // ...
        }
    }
   ```
2. Set tooltip text for user control instance in parent control designer. This adds in .designer file:

   ```
    this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.someUserControl1, "Some text.");
   ```
3. Call **SetToolTip** method of user control instance with **ToolTip** parent control instance from parent control's constructor:

   ```
    public partial class ParentForm : Form
    {
        public ParentForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            someUserControl1.SetToolTip(toolTip1);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to implement a serialized ToolTip property:

```
public partial class YourControlClass : UserControl
    {
    // Serialized property.
    private ToolTip toolTip = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();

    // Public and designer access to the property.
    public string ToolTip
        {
        get
            {
            return toolTip.GetToolTip(this);
            }
        set
            {
            toolTip.SetToolTip(this, value);
            }
        }
```